# pass n number of argument to bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I wanted to pass 2 fixed and remaining 'n' number of arguments to the script which I wanted to store in an array variable. Could someone please suggest how to achieve this via code. Example:

```
sh myScript.sh fixedArgument1 fixedArgument2 var1 var2 ... varN
```

N can be anything but not more than 15.

Also, I can get the value of fixedArgument1 in script via $1 and fixedArgument2 $2 but how to put the remaining arguments in array variable.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: The Bourne shell ( sh )

Comment: The Bourne shell does not know arrays.

Comment: @cyrus since the question is specifically about arrays, it seems more appropriate to keep the `bash` tag and remove the `sh` tag.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I have reversed my change.

Comment: @sagarverma: Please show output of `sh -c 'a[0]=0'`.

Comment: Above command did not print any result after successful run.

Comment: @sagarverma: Then you do not use an original Bourne shell but a shell that can handle arrays. Otherwise, you would have gotten the output: `sh: 1: a[0]=0: not found`

Comment: Oh okay. Understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just shift off the fixed position arguments and get the remainder with `"$@"`.  eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo first arg: "$1"
echo 2nd arg: "$2"
shift
shift
array=("$@")
for element in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$element"
done
```

Make sure you're using a shell that supports arrays.  `sh` may not, as `/bin/sh` is often not `bash`.

But note that it sounds like you are probably working too hard.  Why bother putting the arguments in an array at all?  You can access them via `$@` just as easily as you will access them from the array, and it probably makes more sense to do that.  The array is probably just going to obfuscate the code.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "first arg: '$1'"
echo "2nd arg: '$2'"
shift 2  # discard the first two arguments
if test $# -gt 0; then
    echo There are $# arguments remaining:
    i=1
    # Iterate over the remaining arguments
    for x; do echo "arg $((i++)): '$x'"; done
fi
```

Comment: I have not used ```$n``` before and how we can know how many exact number of arguments are there. Can you pls share an example if possible.

Comment: `$#` tells you the number of arguments.  My `$n` was an attempt to generically refer to `$1`, `$2`, etc.  You can iterate over all the arguments by inspecting `$@`.  The common idiom is `for x in "$@"; do ...; done`, which is so common that you can abbreviate it with `for x; do ...; done`

Comment: thanks for detailed description. It looks like better option to do. I will follow the same and will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `shift; shift`, you can also `shift 2`

Comment: @LéaGris Thanks!  I always forget about that.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

function main {
    local arg1=$1 arg2=$2 remaining=("${@:3}")
    ...
}

main "$@"
```

Also as suggested already, you don't need to store remaining arguments to an array, and you can access it directly either through `"${@:3}"`, or through `"$@"` after executing `shift 2`.  In a `for` loop the `in ...` part can be ignored if target is `"$@"` and positional parameters aren't modified inside the loop through `set --` since this may or may not affect the loop arguments depending on implementation.